# how to use epoch time in php by adding time offset value

Tags: php, datetime, unix, timestamp, epoch

I have this hex `2a ba ce 21` which I have converted to decimal `716885537`, now what I have asked to do is:
`2a ba ce 21` is given; now print last updated time in seconds (seconds that have elapsed since January 1 Midnight, 2000) - 4 Byte
**For converting to standard epoch time, add time offset value 946684800 (time offset from Jan. 1970 to Jan. 2000)**

I have searched alot and to be honest every thing got mixed... It would be great help if some one tell me how to do this in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> every thing got mixed...

Trying to unmix the things…
Presumably your hex bytes are in little-endian order, so you have to reverse before converting.

```
<?php
$timestamp = hexdec(implode(array_reverse(explode(' ', '2a ba ce 21'))));
echo "seconds:  ", $timestamp+946684800, "\n";
echo "readable: ", date('r', $timestamp+946684800), "\n";
```

> what if i had to convert 2c 00 to last updated time in milliseconds as well that is of 2 byte.

The conversion goes just like above. If you want to join the milliseconds to the timestamp, add them divided by 1000 to it.

```
$timestamp = hexdec(implode(array_reverse(explode(' ', '2a ba ce 21'))));
$millisecs = hexdec(implode(array_reverse(explode(' ', '2c 00'))));
$timestamp += 946684800 + $millisecs/1000;
echo "seconds:  ", $timestamp, "\n";
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo "readable: ", date('Y-m-d H:i:s.', $timestamp).substr("00$millisecs", -3), "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you so much, one thing as well what if i had to convert  2c 00 to last updated time in milliseconds as well that is of 2 byte.

Comment: @Muhammad Bilal - I expanded the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much...this is what i was looking for XD